# A matplotlib function in python to visualize data points having a specific condition to have different colors than the others?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to implement anomaly detection using the z score and I want to plot all the data points in blue and only the anomaly in red.

```
import numpy as np
# random data points to calculate z-score
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]

mean = np.mean(data) 

sd = np.std(data)

threshold = 2

outliers = []

for i in data: 
    z = (i-mean)/sd # calculate z-score
    if abs(z) > threshold:  # identify outliers
        outliers.append(i)
```

Can somebody help me visualize the data with blue color for normal data [1, 2,3,4] and red color for data [100] in the same plot using matplotlib using scatter points?

Note: I'm very very new to python, so you're helping is much appreciated.

[The expected plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HGJZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-12', freq='D')
data = pd.Series([5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1, 8, 4, 6, 130, 3, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'data': data})

# Calculate the interquartile range (IQR)
q1, q3 = df['data'].quantile([0.25, 0.75])
iqr = q3 - q1

# Define a threshold for outlier detection
outlier_threshold = 1.5 * iqr

# Find the outliers
outliers = df[(df['data'] < q1 - outlier_threshold) | (df['data'] > q3 + outlier_threshold)]

# Plot the data, marking the outliers in red
plt.plot(df['time'], df['data'], color='blue')
plt.plot(outliers['time'], outliers['data'], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

For drawing as scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-12', freq='D')
data = pd.Series([5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1, 8, 4, 6, 130, 3, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'data': data})
q1, q3 = df['data'].quantile([0.25, 0.75])
iqr = q3 - q1
outlier_threshold = 1.5 * iqr
outliers = df[(df['data'] < q1 - outlier_threshold) | (df['data'] > q3 + outlier_threshold)]
plt.scatter(df['time'], df['data'], color='blue')
plt.scatter(outliers['time'], outliers['data'], color='red')
plt.show()
```

If you want each

```
time = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-12', freq='D')
data = pd.Series([5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1, 8, 4, 6, 130, 3, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'data': data})
q1, q3 = df['data'].quantile([0.25, 0.75])
iqr = q3 - q1
outlier_threshold = 1.5 * iqr
outliers = df[(df['data'] < q1 - outlier_threshold) | (df['data'] > q3 + outlier_threshold)]
plt.scatter(df['time'], df['data'], color='blue')
plt.plot(df['time'], df['data'], color='blue')
plt.scatter(outliers['time'], outliers['data'], color='red')    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, however i didn't understand the use of IQR

Comment: This threshold is typically set to 1.5 times the IQR, which is a commonly used rule of thumb for identifying potential outliers in a dataset. Any values that fall below Q1 - 1.5IQR or above Q3 + 1.5IQR are considered potential outliers.

Comment: There's a csv with 2 columns date and Data. I need to identify anomaly within it using z score and i get some anomaly. I have to plot scatter plot with red colour for the anomaly data and blue for the rest. how do i do that in matplotlib?

Comment: I edited code to drawing scatter.

Comment: In your example photo there was a line plot.

Comment: I added all probabilities you want )

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this with minimal changes to the existing code would look something like below. Note I used median instead of mean here. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt ## Matplotlib for plotting
# random data points to calculate z-score
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]
date = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2023-01-01', freq='Y').tolist() ##Dates
mean = np.median(data) ## Used Median here
sd = np.std(data)
threshold = 2
outliers = []
for i in data: 
    z = (i-mean)/sd # calculate z-score
    if abs(z) > threshold:  # identify outliers
        outliers.append(i)

plt.scatter(date, data, marker='o') ## Plot the data - line plot is default
if len(outliers) > 0:
    for item in outliers:
        plt.scatter(date[data.index(item)], item, c='red', zorder=5) ##Plot the dots - scatter plot
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, However, when using a time series data with 2 columns date and data, I'm getting a 'RangeIndex' object is not callable error in the last (data.index(item), item) line of code.

Comment: There's a csv with 2 columns date and Data. I need to identify anomaly within it using z score and i get some anomaly. I have to plot scatter plot with red colour for the anomaly data and blue for the rest. how do i do that in matplotlib

Comment: Updated code above...

Comment: same error, the data has a timestamp in the csv in a column called date, i took data and date as the ones in csv using panda. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Your question does not have any of the information that are you now coming up with. You will need to provide the data in your csv file and code you are using to read the file. Only then can someone replicate the issue

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured it out. Thank you so much and sorry for the incomplete follow up.